# How is rooting done under the hood?

Tags: root-access

I recently rooted my device which got me curious regarding the process. I would really like to understand how rooting applications work under the hood. Articles I have found over the internet have been very vague. I really would like to root my device all by myself. How can I get started with the same? Id really appreciate some guidance and/or pointers.

Comment: Have you done any research on say http://forum.xda-developers.com/ that would probably be your best bet. Or even http://freaktab.com/ they have some really nice people willing to help out and point better direction.

Comment: Please read the android tag.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it involves exploiting some vulnerabilities(for example, a buffer overflow) in Linux kernel to gain advanced privileges. The exact technique used varies with devices and Android versions.
 This Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889831/how-rooting-is-achieved-programmatically) should give some idea.
 Androidcentral has a [page](http://www.androidcentral.com/root) that gives more information on root.